# How to link open file (image) from latex pdf document within the same folder?

Tags: graphics, hyperref, links, linux

I'm trying to link *soli1.png* and *soli2.png*, willing to redirect the reader to the images but the *image viewer (eog)* stays loading and then it disappears (look at the top in the following order ). I've tried several ways ("run:./soli1","run:./soli1.png","run:./soli1.jpg" (I have also a jpg version), "run:soli1.png", \url ...) of changing the path (I want to keep it relative), without success. The thing is that I know the path is well written.

[image: Line of code]

Line of code

[image: Preamble]

Preamble

Folder:

```
|-report_ji1.pdf
|-soli1.png/jpg
|-soli2.png/jpg
```

My friend got the same result in its machine so I'm becoming crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\href` tag by default opens pdf files, what I would recommend is to convert the images to different pdf's and change the extension inside the link so the image can be open outside the text generated in a new window.

```
\href{run:./soli2.pdf}{soli1}
```

Because the `\href` command has some problems when it tries to open an image in the different OS where the link is not broken but the launch action does not take place.

Comment: the problem is not with `\href`, but with pdf readers: the only link types that work for most of them are links to external URL's (URI), and local links to pdf-files (GoToR). Other types often work only in adobe, or a small set of readers. Beside this: you don't need  `run:`, `\href{soli2.pdf}{soli2}` should work fine.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks everyone